# Intuition behind using GridSearchCV with full data VS with data that only includes statistically significant variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, gridsearchcv

I have an intuition-based question.

I am working on personal project in which I test performance of Machine Learning models first using dataset will all explanatory variables, and then using dataset with only statistically significant variables that have p-values of below 0.06. For both models, I use GridSearchCV for hyperparameter tuning. Please see code below for how I approach my work:

**Analyzing ML performance with full data**

```
my_df_data_full     = my_df.loc[ :, variables['full']]
my_df_target       = my_df.loc[ :, 'Outcome']
```

**Analyzing ML performance with sig (significant) data**

```
my_df_data_sig     = my_df.loc[ :, variables['sig']]
my_df_target       = my_df.loc[ :, 'Outcome']
```

Once that segmentation is done and after declaring train-test-split, I use GridSearchCV as such:

```
    # Declaring a hyper-parameter space
n_estimators_space       = pd.np.arange(100, 1100, 200)
min_samples_leaf_space   = pd.np.arange(1, 51, 10)
criterion_space          = ['gini', 'entropy']
bootstrap_space          = [True, False]
warm_start_space         = [True, False]

# Creating a hyper-parameter grid
param_grid = {'n_estimators'     : n_estimators_space,
              'min_samples_leaf' : min_samples_leaf_space,
              'criterion'        : criterion_space,
              'bootstrap'        : bootstrap_space,
              'warm_start'       : warm_start_space}

# Instantiating the Random Forest Classifier model
random_forest_sig_tuned = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 331)

# GridSearchCV object
random_forest_sig_tuned_cv =\
GridSearchCV(estimator = random_forest_sig_tuned,
             param_grid = param_grid,
             cv = 5,
             scoring = make_scorer(roc_auc_score,
                                   needs_threshold = False))

# Fitting to the full data set
random_forest_sig_tuned_cv.fit(my_df_data, my_df_target)

# Printing the results
print("Tuned parameters:", random_forest_sig_tuned_cv.best_params_)
print("Tuned training AUC:", random_forest_sig_tuned_cv.best_score_.round(4))
```

During my 6-months long Master's in Business Analytics, my professor emphasized that when using GridSearchCV, it is a must to fit to the full dataset due to cross validation. This is clear to me when I use data with all explanatory variables. However, when I am working with data that only contains statistically significant explanatory variables, is it appropriate to fit the data to dataset with only significant variables, or is it a must to always fit data on entire dataset containing all explanatory variables?

In other words, under "Fitting to the full dataset" section of my GridSearchCV code, is it okay to fit to my_df_data_sig in case when I work with my_df_data_sig? Or, even if I work with my_df_data_sig, I still have to fit to my_df_data_full?

Comment: How do you define "significance"? What could be insignificant for one algo maybe significant for another. In general its not recommended prefilter variables for an algo with a "significance" from another (search for opinion from Max Kuhn, R caret package author). So I believe your professor is right.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't make any sense to mandate that you use the entire dataset including insignificant variables. You'd end up being forced to include information that is useless, such as userIDs.

I believe what your professor was likely trying to stress is that you should use all the training examples (Training set and Validation Set), rather than all the features including the gibberish ones. Of course you'll still holdout the test set data to avoid overestimating your model strength.